# Binding IDatabaseInitializer<> in my test to test my  data context initialzer (EntityFramework 4.1 aka EF4 Code First)

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework, nunit, ninject, service-locator

I'm trying inject my database initializer so that I can use test data initializer in my unit test and the real one in production.

Here is my ninject module.

```
class IocBindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<DbContext>()
            .To<ActualEntityFrameworkDataContext>();

        Bind(typeof(IDatabaseInitializer<>))
            .To(typeof(TestDataContextInitializer));

    }
}
```

As you can see there is only one binding is defined; however when I run the test it fails do to the following exception:

```
Ninject.ActivationException : Error activating IDatabaseInitializer{TContext} More than one matching bindings are available.
```

I have a base testfixture in which I instantiate the kernel ans pass it into common service locator:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestContext
{
    private IKernel NinjectKernel { get; set; }

    [SetUp]
    public void setup()
    {
        NinjectKernel = new StandardKernel(new INinjectModule[] { new IocBindings() } );
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new NinjectServiceLocator(NinjectKernel));
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDownAttribute()
    {
        NinjectKernel.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I'm new to ninject so I'm not sure if I have set it up correctly.

any help in how to resolve this issue is very welcomed.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the problem with my source code, but if I use the following line of code, I get no exception. Obviously, this is the only workaround!

```
Bind<DbContext>()
            .To<ActualEntityFrameworkDataContext>()
            .OnActivation(dbContext => (new TestDataContextInitializer()).InitializeDatabase(dbContext as ActualEntityFrameworkDataContext));
```